# Moving from VS Professional to VS Team System

Tags: visual-studio-2008

We are looking at moving from Visual Studio 2008 Professional to Visual Studio Team System. I believe I've read that the client Development Edition is a superset of what Professional has/does. I'd like to ease into the transition with the client end first, then get the Team Foundation Server up and running later, and I want to be sure I won't be losing any functionality. If all goes well, the rest of my team will be following along with the upgrade. Let me know if this sounds like the right direction to go, or if you've had issues migrating in this direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Team System (Developer / Suite ) is a superset of Professional and as such, you only gain features by upgrading. Tester is a slightly different feature set, although it is included in Suite.

The most common way of transitioning is to upgrade all of the dev stations at once.  There's no reason not to.

As far as going with Team Foundation Server, that takes a little more planning depending on your source control and project management needs; which is a conversation in and of itself.